# Angular 7 App not working in IE11 (internet explore) Getting Error: SCRIPT1002

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular7

Angular 7 app is not working in IE11 getting below Error 
Getting Error: SCRIPT1002
vendor.js (142286,1)

[image: Console]

[image: when i click on error in console it's taking me to vendor.js file in debugger]

Comment: IE11 is end of life and doesn’t support modern JavaScript. I recommend placing a message for IE11 users stating to use a different browser (Edge is compatible, as are Firefox, Chrome, and Safari).

Comment: @theMayer But from the offcial site they say , IE11,10,9 Supports

Comment: I personally won’t design for IEx unless I’m explicitly instructed to, and even in that case the customer is going to be told of the cost so they can make a management decision as to the value of that decision. Not even the government is requiring IE support anymore.

Comment: what operations are you doing, and  will cause this problem? can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You need polyfills for IE support. Check `polyfills.ts` file in your Angular project. There's a direction for IE support.

polyfills.ts:

```
...
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
...
```

**Update:**

set target to es5 in `tsconfig.json`.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this will make the app load, the user experience will break in unoredicatable ways when using these older browsers (as the caveat on Angular’s web site about older browsers indicates).

Comment: @Raw_nk I missed one thing. You need set target option in  `tsconfig.json`. I've edited my post.

Comment: @zmag I have set target option in tsconfig.json Still getting same error.

Comment: I got an error 'Can't resolve ...' for each import. Fixed it with removing every number. So import everything with only 'es' instead of 'es6': `import 'core-js/es/symbol';` and so on